# Executar um macro no VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Preciso executar um macro dentro de um **Select Case** e mandar uma mensagem com o nome do macro que foi executado. O código envia a mensagem mas não executa o macro.

Tenho um combobox com os valores de **v** (cmbLista).
Os macros que quero executar estão no Módulo4

```
Sub adMacro()
Dim v As String

v = cmbLista.Value
Select Case v
    Case v = "BDCTE": Módulo4.BDCTE
    Case v = "BDCTELog": Módulo4.BDCTELog
    
    End Select
    
    MsgBox v
    
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se era só isso, seu erro está na sintaxe, como se estivesse atribuindo um novo valor à V.
Eu iria comentar mas não tenho pontos o bastante, então estou colocando como resposta.

```
Sub adMacro()

  Dim v As String

  v = cmbLista.Value

  Select Case v
    Case "BDCTE": 
      Módulo4.BDCTE
    Case "BDCTELog": 
      Módulo4.BDCTELog
  End Select
    
  MsgBox v
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu